# Bluetooth COM serial port doesn't become available after un-pairing

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, bluetooth, motorola-emdk

Using the Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth class from Motorola EMDK 2.4 I am trying to pair to a device (A zebra MZ220 in this case) to my mobile device (a Motorola MC75a running Windows Mobile 6.5.3).

I pair with the printer as follows:

```
bluetooth.RemoteDevices.UnPairAll(); 
RemoteDevice rd = new RemoteDevice(_name, _address, "Serial");
rd.LocalComPort = _commPortNumber;    
rd.Pair();
```

If I try and pair with another printer or even rebind the same printer it sometimes fails because the COM port is unavailable as confirmed by investigating

```
bluetooth.LocalComPorts;
```

From my investigations and checking whilst debugging it seems bluetooth.RemoteDevices.UnPairAll(); sometimes frees the COM port but roughly 80% of the time doesn't.

Is there anyway to forcibly free the port using either the Motorola EMDK or any other method?

Comment: I've had the same kinds of problems with the Symbol Bluetooth API, but I wasn't sure if it was the printer (it happened to be a protoype unit).  The Zebra SDK is better, but is targeted towards their printers (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

[Zebra has a mobile SDK for windows mobile devices](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/SDK.html). It handles all of the comm stuff and has a bunch of good examples and nice documentation.